# How to manage a lifetime of an infinite observable when it's dictated by the subscriber not the source

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I'm pushing data updates/changes using IObservable, I have a method that gets the latest data from a database `GetLatestElement`, whenever anyone calls an `UpdateElement` and the data gets updated, a message is distributed over a messaging system.

So I'm creating an observable that emits the latest value, and then re-emits the new value when it receives the update event form the messaging system:

```
public IObservable<IElement> GetElement(Guid id)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>((observer) =>
    {
        observer.OnNext(GetLatestElement(id));

        // subscribe to internal or external update notifications
        var messageCallback = (message) =>
        {
            // new update message recieved,
            observer.OnNext(GetLatestElement(id));
        }
        messageService.SubscribeToTopic(id, messageCallback);

        return Disposable.Create(() => Console.Writeline("Observer Disposed"));
    });
}
```

My problem is that this is indefinite. These updates will potentially happen forever. Since I'm trying to get the system as state-less as possible, a new Observable is created for each request for `GetElementType`. This means the lifetime is dictated by the *subscriber*, not the source of the data.

I'll never call `OnComplete()` in the Observable, I want to complete when the Observer/User is done.

However, I need to call `messageService.Unsubscribe(messageCallback);` at some point in time in order to unsubscribe from the messages when the Observable is done with.

I could do this when the subscription is disposed, but then I can only subscribe a single time, which seems likely to introduce bugs.

How should this be done with Observables?

Comment: Maybe Complete it in your `Disposable.Create` handler then? By the way you probably mean "infinite", not "indefinite".

Comment: Ah, I see. I assumed that was disposing the IObservable (when I thought IObservable was disposable) so it was effectively completing it. That would be a solution but it would limit my observables to a single subscription, which it would be nice not to have to do.

Comment: To be honest I don't see a reason to complete this sequence. When subsriber unsubsribes - you remove `messageCallback` from `messageService` so there are no resources that will leak. When you complete sequence - you notify subscribers that it is done. But in your case as you said - you don't need this, because subscriber knows himself when it is done. So just don't complete it.

Comment: That means I can only subscribe once ever. So if I use Take(1) at any point, or any other methods that unsubscribe, it'll break any active subscriptions. I've edited the question a little.

Comment: That is only true if your `messageService` is implemented incorrectly. When you call `Subscribe` mutliple times with the same id but different callbacks - it should add those callbacks to a list and call them all when update arrives. And when you unsubsribe - you should pass id and callback and it should remove only that callback from the list.

Comment: Yes, it's implemented with removing from a list of callbacks. However, if I get an observable, say `elementObservable = GetElement(id)`, then the observable is created and MS callback added. Then I subscribe `elementObservable .Take(1).Subscribe(value => doNothing)`, that subscription is created, then disposed of almost immediately. Thus the MS callback is removed. Now later I subscribe to that same `elementObservable.Subscribe(value => doLoadsOfStuff).` the callback was removed by the earlier subscription. Unless I'm completely misunderstanding how things work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is some misunderstanding about how `Observable.Create` works. Whenever you call `Subscribe` on the result of your `GetElement()` - the body of `Observable.Create` is executed. So for each subscriber you have **separate** subscription to your `messageService` with separate callback to execute. If you unsubscribe - you only remove subscription of *that* subscriber. All other remain active, because they have their own `messageCallback`. That is assuming of course that `messageService` is implemented properly. Here is sample application illustrating that:

```
static IElement  GetLatestElement(Guid id) {
    return new Element();
}

public class Element : IElement {

}

public interface IElement {

}

class MessageService {
    private Dictionary<Guid, Dictionary<Action<IElement>, CancellationTokenSource>> _subs = new Dictionary<Guid, Dictionary<Action<IElement>, CancellationTokenSource>>();
    public void SubscribeToTopic(Guid id, Action<IElement> callback) {
        var ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
        if (!_subs.ContainsKey(id))
            _subs[id] = new Dictionary<Action<IElement>, CancellationTokenSource>();
        _subs[id].Add(callback, ct);
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested) {
                callback(new Element());
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        });
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(Guid id, Action<IElement> callback) {
        _subs[id][callback].Cancel();
        _subs[id].Remove(callback);
    }
}

public static IObservable<IElement> GetElement(Guid id)
{
    var messageService = new MessageService();
    return Observable.Create<IElement>((observer) =>
    {
        observer.OnNext(GetLatestElement(id));

        // subscribe to internal or external update notifications
        Action<IElement> messageCallback = (message) =>
        {
            // new update message recieved,
            observer.OnNext(GetLatestElement(id));
        };
        messageService.SubscribeToTopic(id, messageCallback);

        return Disposable.Create(() => {
            messageService.Unsubscribe(id, messageCallback);
            Console.WriteLine("Observer Disposed");
        });
    });
}

public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var ob = GetElement(Guid.NewGuid());
    var sub1 = ob.Subscribe(c =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("got element");
    });

    var sub2 = ob.Subscribe(c =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("got element 2");
    });
    // at this point we see both subscribers receive messages
    Console.ReadKey();
    sub1.Dispose();
    // first one is unsubscribed, but second one is still alive
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

So as I said it comments - I see no reason to complete your observable in this case.

Comment: I see, yes, I fundamentally misunderstood observable creation. I assumed the callback in Observable.Create was called once on creation, but I understand now. It's called once per subscription. Makes sense, given that the Create method get's a copy of the Observer. Thanks for helping to clear that up.

Comment: Do you think, in this case, it would be more sensible to use a Subject (or RecordSubject with a single item buffer)? In that case, a new observer isn't created each subscription (but just provided with the latest value) and it allows me reduce extra subscriptions (and thus message load).

Comment: I think reading this will enlighten you in this regard: http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html. In short, if you want to share your service subscription - you need to turn your cold observable into hot, for example using Publish and RefCount, just as another answer suggests.

Comment: Thanks. I'd come across that page, but I think I now have the context to understand it a lot more. Publish and RefCount look like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

As Evk pointed out, `Observable.Create` runs then disposes almost immediately. If you want to keep the `messageService` subscription open though, Rx can help you with that. Look at `MessageObservableProvider`. The rest is just to make things compile:

```
public class MessageObservableProvider
{
    private MessageService messageService;
    private Dictionary<Guid, IObservable<Unit>> _messageNotifications = new Dictionary<Guid, IObservable<Unit>>();
    private IObservable<Unit> GetMessageNotifications(Guid id)
    {
        return Observable.Create<Unit>((observer) =>
        {
            Action<Message> messageCallback = _ => observer.OnNext(Unit.Default);
            messageService.SubscribeToTopic(id, messageCallback);

            return Disposable.Create(() =>
            {
                messageService.Unsubscribe(messageCallback);
                Console.WriteLine("Observer Disposed");
            });
        });
    }

    public IObservable<IElement> GetElement(Guid id)
    {
        if(!_messageNotifications.ContainsKey(id))
            _messageNotifications[id] = GetMessageNotifications(id).Publish().RefCount();

        return _messageNotifications[id]
            .Select(_ => GetLatestElement(id))
            .StartWith(GetLatestElement(id));
    }

    private IElement GetLatestElement(Guid id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class IElement { }
public class Message { }
public class MessageService
{
    public void SubscribeToTopic(Guid id, Action<Message> callback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(Action<Message> callback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Your original `Create` implementation incorporated the functionality of a `StartWith` and a `Select`. I moved those out, so now the `Observable.Create` just returns a notification when a new message is available.

More importantly though, in `GetElement` there's now a `.Publish().RefCount()` call. This will leave the `messageService` subscription open (by not calling `.Dispose()`) as long as there's at least one child observable (subscription) hanging around.